# Amazon S3 validate user before returning files

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, amazon-s3, firebase-storage

I'm building an app that authenticates users and then return their generated files.

I'm using *Amazon S3* to store such files. The *Public block access* is disabled and the Policy is set in way that only an IAM User can access to the main bucket.

What I only need is returning these files to **authenticated users**.

I see that a way to achieve this is creating **presigned url** and it works, but such url will be available for anyone that has the link.

I know I can set a *time limit* like 1 minute, but it doesn't resolve my problem completely. Maybe I can solve this by using *Amazon Cognito*, but it forces me to use their Authentication flow, which I don't want to (I plan to use *Firebase Auth*).

If you know *Firebase Cloud Storage* then you know that I can easily achieve this through *Firebase Storage Rules*.

So my questions are:

- How can I achieve this in *Amazon S3*? I mean if there is an option to validate in the backend
- Is this really possible, or I'm forced to use services such *Google Cloud Storage*?

Comment: You need an authentication mechanism. If you don't want to use Cognito, that's ok, but what *are* you going to use? Typically your users would authenticate to a backend app server via some identity provider (such as Cognito, Facebook, Google) and that app server would mediate access to the user's private files. Also, look at Amplify.

Comment: What is your concern about the presigned URL time limit? Are you worried that they might share the link with somebody else, who can then download the file? Is this any worse than the person simply sharing the downloaded file with somebody else? What is your actual use-case that you are wanting to achieve?